Deploy to Azure failing with Error: ENOTFOUND
I have repository with simple .net web api that I want to deploy to Azure. However my deploy is always failing with this error:

The workflow file can be found here.
Does anybody know what is the cause of this error?

Go to azure Dashboard had to the Your Web App services From Deployment Setting Remove GitHub Integration From There And try to re-deploy Your project using only CI/CD pipeline make sure to backup you CI/CD pipeline file Backup.

Can you please share screenshots? I cannot find menu options you are talking about.
